# MySQL: Is there a way to return a list of functions / procedures filtered by a string found within the code?

Tags: mysql, function, stored-procedures

Basically I have the unenviable position of updating our entire system to stop using a certain table and instead use another one.  I've already done this for all of our code, now I need to do it for all of our functions and procedures.

I know that I can get a list of the functions / procedures in a database as such:

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES
```

I also know that I can look at the code for an individual function / procedure as such:

```
SHOW CREATE FUNCTION function_name
SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE procedure_name
```

However, I don't want to have to look through each function and procedure one by one, as we have over 200 of them.

I'm wondering if there is anything like...

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES WHERE code_column_name LIKE '%search_string%'
```

There doesn't seem to be any column in INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES that contains the code, but... is there a way to do this on a different table perhaps?

Comment: The column in INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES is called `routine_definition`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT * FROM mysql.proc WHERE body LIKE '%search_string%'
```

Comment: Hmm, that doesn't seem to get all of them.  SELECT * FROM mysql.proc WHERE body LIKE '%search_string%' returns more, so maybe that would work?  I don't know for sure that it gets all of them either though, not really sure what the difference between body and body_utf8 is?

Comment: Doing an "or" on both body and body_utf8 gets me the same number of results as just body alone.  I'm thinking maybe body does it?

Comment: What is your default charset? And what is the output of `SELECT count(*), sum(body = body_utf8) FROM mysql.proc` ?

Comment: I'm honestly not sure what the default charset is?  How would I find that out?  When I run that command it returns count(*) 109, sum(body = body_utf8) 12.

Comment: `SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'character_set_%'`. Looks like you have a lot of SPs where body is not the same as body_utf8. Do `SELECT * FROM mysql.proc WHERE body != body_utf8 LIMIT 10 /* or so*/` to get a sample and see why.

Comment: Hmm, when I do "SELECT * FROM mysql.proc WHERE body != body_utf8" I only get two results.  Both of them have the SQL in the body field and nothing in the body_utf8 field. "SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'character_set_%'" gives me utf8 for character_set_system and latin1 for a bunch of other fields.

Comment: body_utf8 column appeared in MySQL 5.1.22. Is it possible that the SPs with the empty body_utf8 column came from a pre-5.1.22 installation without ever being converted (via mysql_upgrade script)?

Comment: It's possible.  BTW I'm realizing now that "SELECT * FROM mysql.proc WHERE body != body_utf8" is not returning results where one or the other is NULL.  For instance this "SELECT * FROM mysql.proc WHERE body IS NOT NULL && body_utf8 IS NULL" gives me 95 results.

Answer (score 0):

I would use UNIX grep for that.

If you output the results of show create function/procedure to a flat file on disk then run grep on it.  Or turn it directly thru grep.

Here is one way to do it:

```
echo 'show create function foo' | mysql -h*host* -u*user* -p*pass* *schema* | grep *obsolete-tablename*
```

or dump the entire database to disk and then grep it.

```
mysqldump -h*host* -u*user* -p*pass* *schema --routines > mydump.sql
grep *obsolete-tablename mydump.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

You asked about MySQL but I will just mention that I use this for stored procedures in MS SQL Server:

```
SELECT object_name(id)
FROM syscomments
WHERE text LIKE '%wibble%'
```

The `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES` table (which you mention) also contains similar stuff, but the text is cut off after 4000 chars, so you find less matches; not very helpful.